# Printing format string results in syntax error

Tags: ruby

I just started learning ruby and I have come across a problem.

The following works as expected

```
games = "%{first} %{second}"
puts games % {first: "halo", second: "fallout"}
```

But this does not

```
games = "%{1} %{2}"
puts games % {1: "halo", 2: "fallout"}
```

Which results in `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input`

Can someone explain why I cannot use numeric values for names instead of string values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hash rocket for numbered keys, `1 => "halo"` also I'm pretty sure you can't use numbers for format string keys.

Comment: Really? I got a 'couldn't find key called '1' kinda error when I tried it, guess I was doing it wrong.